# What do HC and HL (hamiltonian graph problems) stand for?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

Hopefully, this question is fine.

I'm referring to the NP-complete problems regarding [hamiltonian graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

- I suppose the C in HC is from Cycle or Circuit. It seems like Circuit is more popular.
- HL (called HAMPATH sometimes) is a bit more difficult. HL deals with hamiltonian paths (HP is already in use, of course). My best guess is that since path graphs are also called linear graphs, the L may stand for Linear. Another possibility is Line.

Comment: The Wikipedia article doesn't mention either HC nor HL. Where did you encounter these terms? The material you are reading should define them. Otherwise, how could we possibly know?

Comment: I've never even considered the possibility these were not widespread terms. But you're absolutely right. Now that I think about it, these might not be used as much as I thought. Still, I've seen some uses (mostly HC and its directed variant, DHC) outside of my university, so perhaps someone would know...

Comment: Seems like a popular name for HL is HAMPATH.